# iOS - Fill bezierPath with multiple colors based on percentage

Tags: ios, drawing, uibezierpath

I drawed a UIBezierPath in Objective-C and fill it with a red color. Now, I want to fill the path with multiple colors based on percentage. For example: I want to fill the path with 20% green color and the remaining 80% with red color, on top of each other (not a gradient). I also want a few pixels spacing between the fill and the stroke.

I don't know how I can accomplish these things. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this or point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance!

```
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(50, 50)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(60, 90)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(80, 90)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(90, 50)];

bezierPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinBevel;

[UIColor.redColor setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 4;
[bezierPath stroke];
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to fill the path with a single color that is a blend of 20% green and 80% red?  Or do you want to fill 20% of the pixels inside the path with green, and the remaining 80% of the pixels with red?

Comment: I'm sorry; I want to fill 20% of the pixels inside the path with green, and the remaining 80% of the pixels with red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can do this, I have divided the path into 5 parts 20 % of each.

[image]

```
 UIBezierPath* bezierPath = UIBezierPath.bezierPath;
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(50, 50)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(60, 90)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(80, 90)];
[bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(90, 50)];

bezierPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinBevel;

[UIColor.redColor setFill];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 4;
[bezierPath stroke];
[bezierPath addClip];

CGRect boundingBox = CGPathGetBoundingBox(bezierPath.CGPath);

CGRect firstTwentyPercent = CGRectMake(boundingBox.origin.x,
                                       boundingBox.origin.y + boundingBox.size.height - 0.2 * boundingBox.size.height,
                                       boundingBox.size.width,
                                        0.2 * boundingBox.size.height);
[[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(firstTwentyPercent);

CGRect secondTwentyPercent = CGRectMake(boundingBox.origin.x,
                                        boundingBox.origin.y + boundingBox.size.height - 0.4 * boundingBox.size.height,
                                        boundingBox.size.width,
                                        0.2 * boundingBox.size.height);
[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(secondTwentyPercent);


CGRect thirdTwentyPercent = CGRectMake(boundingBox.origin.x,
                                        boundingBox.origin.y + boundingBox.size.height - 0.6 * boundingBox.size.height,
                                        boundingBox.size.width,
                                        0.2 * boundingBox.size.height);
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(thirdTwentyPercent);


CGRect fourthTwentyPercent = CGRectMake(boundingBox.origin.x,
                                       boundingBox.origin.y + boundingBox.size.height - 0.8 * boundingBox.size.height,
                                       boundingBox.size.width,
                                       0.2 * boundingBox.size.height);
[[UIColor cyanColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(fourthTwentyPercent);

CGRect fifthTwentyPercent = CGRectMake(boundingBox.origin.x,
                                        boundingBox.origin.y,
                                        boundingBox.size.width,
                                        0.2 * boundingBox.size.height);
[[UIColor orangeColor] setFill];
UIRectFill(fifthTwentyPercent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you also know how I can get a little margin between the fill colors and the stroke?

Comment: Stroke the path twice after filling.  First stroke it with a larger line width and a white stroke color.  Then stroke it with a narrow line width and a black stroke color.