# iOS: How to fill image with percentage

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to fill image with percentage (e.g. same as rating).

- Actually am showing rating image with with float value.
- Depend upon float value i need to fill the with particular image.

I got result to fill over all image. But my query is to fill image with percentage value.

**My code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _ColImgView.image = [self imageNamed:@"star.png" withColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}

- (UIImage *)imageNamed:(NSString *)name withColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    // load the image

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:name];

    // begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);

    // get a reference to that context we created
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // set the fill color
    [color setFill];

    // translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    // set the blend mode to color burn, and the original image
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColorBurn);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width, img.size.height);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

    // set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (color burn) a colored rectangle
    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, img.CGImage);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

    // generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
    UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //return the color-burned image
    return coloredImg;
}
```

**Preview image:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add overlay. Overlay should be under image and image should be png with transparency. To fill overlay with color in specified area you can use code from here: 
[iOS - Fill bezierPath with multiple colors based on percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28158549/ios-fill-bezierpath-with-multiple-colors-based-on-percentage)

If I will find free time I will write code for you, but for now I can only explain what you should do.